# ActiveMQ Artemis - ha/replicated-failback example - is this working?

Tags: replication, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to run example "ha/replicated-failback" on ApacheMQ Artemis. When I run "mvn verify", it shows the following output, making me think it's working:

[image: messages send and received]

However, the are a bunch of error messages before and after, such as:

```
ReplicatedFailbackStaticExample0-out:java.lang.IllegalStateException: AMQ229230: Failed to bind acceptor netty-acceptor to localhost:61616
```

Also:

[image: ha/replication example target invocation exception]

caused by:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.example.ReplicatedFailbackStaticExample.main (ReplicatedFailbackStaticExample.java:111)
```

And finally:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  31.059 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-12-12T11:30:57-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.activemq:artemis-maven-plugin:2.27.1:runClient (runClient) on project replicated-failback-static: null: MojoFailureException -> [Help 1]
```

My question: is this a successful test? FYI, I've changed the default admin password, I don't know if that would have anything to do with it.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Comment: @JustinBertram Hi Justin, thanks for following up!  Actually we are using Active MQ to implement an HA solution for another product., so we don't necessarily need the HA on Artemis. I was just checking to see what would be needed in case we did. We're sticking with ActiveMQ anyway because it's frankly more compatible with our dev/deploy environment, which is Java-centric.

Comment: When you say, "We're sticking with ActiveMQ anyway because it's frankly more compatible with our dev/deploy environment, which is Java-centric." Which version of ActiveMQ are you sticking with and what specifically is more compatible?

Comment: Also, can you clarify how you're using ActiveMQ "to implement an HA solution for another product"? I'm not sure I've heard of this kind of architecture/use-case before.

Comment: @JustinBertram - It's ActiveMQ Artemis. I prefer it to other products because it's written in Java and implements the JMS protocol, which I've worked with before.

Comment: @JustinBertram The HA solution is essentially to replicate a database message from one server to the other (primary to backup) via ActiveMQ messages. That database doesn't really have a two-way replication capability, so we're using ActiveMQ as an MQTT listener to publish updates ActiveMQ, and have two consumers, the backup and the primary. In case the primary fails, whatever messages are in the queue would be lost, but since the data is not critical, we can live with this.

Comment: Did my answer address your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A result of `BUILD FAILURE` indicates an unsuccessful test. The `NullPointerException` and the `AMQ229230` message also indicate a problem.

When I run `mvn verify` from the `replicated-failback` example of ActiveMQ Artemis 2.27.1 (i.e. the latest release) I don't see any of those kinds of errors.